# exporting textures to godot and getting the file texture out of blender

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, export

I was playing around with textures for the first time and tried to export whole model with textures to Godot, all of my textures are non existent so I researched some ground and it seems I need folder in Godot for textures that will be automatically distributed after i export my model with them. Now I created the folder and I don't really know how to export my texture.
Here it is how it looks to me in blender:
[image]

And now the question is, what can I do to export the texture itself? UV map or the side panel seems like there is no texture at all:

[image]

[image]

I don't really know what can I do to get my texture file now, here it is how it looks in godot:
[image]
[image]

What can I do to extract the texture file along with .blend file ? Maybe there is better option than dragging directly .blend file into Godot?

I must admit it's really neat that I can save .blend files directly in Godot and they will update when i will work on them in blender automatically but it works for me when I work only on materials not textures. I am really new to designing textures in blender and to Godot so I may be missing something obvious.